# Why is my Open Zeppelin import in Remix throwing an error?

Tags: solidity, remix, blockchain, openzeppelin, inheritance

I am importing ERC20 from **OpenZeppelin** but it's not working!

Here is the code:

```js
        // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
    pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
    
    import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
    
    contract lock is ERC20{
        
    }
```

Here is the error:

```js
        TypeError: Contract "lock" should be marked as abstract.
    --> learning/lock.sol:6:1:
    |
    6 | contract lock is ERC20{
    | ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
    Note: Missing implementation:
    --> https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol:54:5:
    |
    54 | constructor(string memory name_, string memory symbol_) {
    | ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
```

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [documentation](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/erc20) of open Zeppelin, you should implement the constructor, otherwise your contract needs to be marked as abstract, as your error also specifies.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract lock is ERC20 {
constructor()...
}
```

Comment: i want to use it for locking contract, i dont need name, supply. when i remove parameters from constructor it gives me same error.

Comment: how about then you edit your question and try to add more information of what you are trying to do, so we can help with that.

Answer (score 0):

> i want to use it for locking contract, i dont need name, supply. when i remove parameters from constructor it gives me same error

I assume that you want to lock a specific token inside your smart contract. To solve this issue, you can use ERC20 smart contract like state variable and access to erc20 smart contract methods.
You can see this example:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract lock {
    ERC20 _token;

    constructor(address _tokenAddress) { 
        _token = ERC20(_tokenAddress);
    }

    // Get name about ERC20 token
    function getName() external view returns(string memory) {
        return _token.name();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using contract inheritance, the child contract must contain the parent contract's constructor arguments or be marked as `abstract`.

If you look at the contract you are trying to inherit, Open Zeppelin's ERC20:

```js
constructor(string memory name_, string memory symbol_) {
        _name = name_;
        _symbol = symbol_;
    }
```

You can see it takes in two constructor arguments: `name_` and `symbol_`.

So in order for your contract to correctly inherit this, you must include the ERC20 constructor in your contract. For example:

```js
contract Token is ERC20 {

    constructor(string memory name_, string memory symbol_) ERC20(name_, symbol_){

    }
}
```

Now you can add any additional/custom logic you'd like to.